# Fazer contagem de elementos vetor e colocar links na pagina

Tags: javascript, array

Quero fazer um *script* que conta quantos indice de vetor tenho dentro `new Array`.

## Exemplo

```
var array = new Array('001.html', '002.html', '003.html', '004.html', '005.html')
```

.. e adicione-os no documento HTML, logo no corpo `body`, algo do tipo:

```
<a href="001.html">1</a> 

<a href="002.html">2</a> 

<a href="003.html">3</a> 

<a href="004.html">4</a> 

<a href="005.html">5</a>
```

Ficando assim na pagina:

**1 2 3 4 5**

*Apenas preciso de dicas e/ou pequenos exemplos de como conseguir isso.*

Comment: um foreach não resolveria?

Comment: @diegofm Então, estou tentando criar algo com laço `for`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja se isso funciona:

Use um [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), é uma função do array, semelhante ao `.forEach()`, com a diferença de que o retorno da função a cada laço é o que vai substituir o elemento correspondente no array de origem.

```js
var array = new Array('001.html', '002.html', '003.html', '004.html', '005.html')

var html = array.map(function(link, index){
  return "<a href="+ link +" >" + (index+1) + "</a>";  
})

document.body.innerHTML = html.join("<br>")
```

Versão com o `for`:

```js
var array = new Array('001.html', '002.html', '003.html', '004.html', '005.html')

var html = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  html[i] = "<a href="+ array[i] +" >" + (i+1) + "</a>";  
}

document.body.innerHTML = html.join("<br>")
```

Comment: Realmente muito bom ao que necessito. Mas antes desejo saber uma coisa - neste trecho `array.map` rodaria em navegadores obsoleto. Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas nunca o vi

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, roda sim, pode ver sua compatibilidade aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Caraca meu! vai vendo a gente acha que aprendeu tudo. Eu particularmente nunca havia visto `array.map`. Essa é nova vou procurar estudar mais sobre assunto.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, veja mais sobre array aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array :)

Comment: Valeu!!! Sabia que havia mais de uma maneira de fazer a mesma coisa, é bom sempre termos isso em mente. Ficou até melhor eu compreeder a lógica toda.